# Rails outside form information to controller

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm sending form information to an exams controller in my Rails app from a nonRails outside site using:

```
<form action="http://xyzRailsapp.com/exams" method="post" >
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="test" > 
   Name:<input type="text" name="exam[patient_name]" value="#patientname#" >
   Source:<input type="text" name="exam[source]" value="share" > 
</form>
```

Inside the exam controller i am trying to test to see if the value of 'exam[source]' is 'share' by using:

```
if params[:source] == 'patshare'
    format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Ready to share.' 
end
```

but i am obviously getting mixed up by the exam[source] hash structure- how should i rewrite this if-then statement?

Comment: sorry that line should be "if params[:source] == 'share'

Comment: Have you tried inspecting params or any other debugging steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your field is `exam[source]`. You're missing the "exam" part. Its value will be at `params[:exam][:source]`.